# NativeScript is giving this error TypeError: Cannot read property 'loadData' of undefined while creating web-view

Tags: javascript, android, xml, nativescript

[---------------------------------------------------click here for error logs---------------------------------------------------](https://i.stack.imgur.com/744JS.png)
below snippet is the code i used in my app.
i am getting the error in below line

```
 webView.android.loadData(html, 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'utf-8');
```

```js
var vmModule = require("./main-view-model");
var webViewModule = require("ui/web-view");
var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();
var android = android;

function pageLoaded(args) {
    var html = '<html><body><h1>I can fuck?</h1></body><html>';
    var page = args.object;
   // var page = new pageModule.Page();
   // var web = page.getViewById(webViewModule.WebView,"webView");
    var webView = new webViewModule.WebView();
    webView.android.loadData(html, 'text/html; charset=utf-8', 'utf-8');
    page.content = webView;
    return page;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

```html
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView id="webView" colSpan="4" row="2"  />
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

Comment: To load HTML content to the WebView you just need to add HTML source text or path to the `html` file to the WebView `src` property. You could review this thread here - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39994187/how-to-load-files-into-webview-in-native-script/39996590#39996590 . For further help you can review the examples  from docs - https://docs.nativescript.org/cookbook/ui/web-view .

Answer (score 0):

Your code is all wrong; you are creating the component twice and the second time incorrectly.

Here is how to do it:

```
<Page xmlns="http://www.nativescript.org/tns.xsd" loaded="pageLoaded">
    <StackLayout>
        <WebView id="webView"/>
    </StackLayout>
</Page>
```

The source code is:

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var html = '<html><body><h1>Look I work!</h1></body><html>';
    var page = args.object;
    var webView = page.getViewById("webview");
    webView.src = html;
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Unless you need to access the `webView.android` or `webView.ios` property, it is always much better to use the framework when possible.  The code I wrote above will work properly on both iOS and android with no other changes!     Where your version of the code (if we fixed it) would only work on Android.

---

If you want to load a web page; then the pageLoaded function is:

```
function pageLoaded(args) {
    var page = args.object;
    var webView = page.getViewById("webview");
    webView.src = "http://nativescript.rocks";
}
exports.pageLoaded = pageLoaded;
```

Comment: i want to load index.html on web view. how can i achieve that ?

Comment: Added code to show how to load a html site.   IF you want a file; it is just `"~/path/to/file.html"` as the src instead...